# How to programatically fetch the download status of Google Chrome?

Tags: bash, python, google-chrome, scripts, perl

How would I go about determining if Google Chrome is downloading something, and getting the "percent-done" value of that download, from the terminal using a Python, Perl, or Bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can. To get the Chromium progress bar to work in Unity launcher, the flow of information is in reverse. Chromium is *telling* Unity about the progress rather than Unity *asking*. You can see the API used for that [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Progress).